# skip accept cookies, 2nd time in the loop Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a script that takes an image from google images and then pastes it somewhere. When starting the script, it does everything as it is supposed to, including accepting the "Before you continue to Google" cookies pop up. When the script enters the loop for the 2nd time the Google cookie pop-up doesn't show up anymore so I guess I would have to skip the steps to accept the cookies. This is what I have tried -

```
        def get_image(title):
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
        driver.get('https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=EN')
        time.sleep(10)
        while True:
            try:
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/span/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/button[2]').click()
            except TimeoutException as e:
                print(e)
                continue
            else:
                Rest of the script...
```

When the script runs for the 2nd time it shows this error -
`raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: {Alert text :  Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }`

Full XPATH to the cookies Accept All button - `/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/span/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/button[2]/div`

Comment: Post a minimal reprodductible example. based on the error you receive, there is some sort of alert when you run it a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple check, wether it's the accept cookie page like:

```
if driver.title.startswith('Before'):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/span/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/button[2]').click()
```